# PHP show associative array content into JSON format

Tags: php, arrays, json, database, associative-array

i'm new in PHP language. I'm writing a PHP script to get information from my online database(created on my altervista personal webpage) and convert in JSON format.
The problem is about when i get elements from my database i can show them correctly using "echo" command, but when i parse associative array to "json_encode" function i can't see correctly elements.

Here is the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM People";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$json_array = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "" . $key . ": " . $value;
        echo "<br>";
        $json_array[] = array(''=>$key, ''=>$value);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo json_encode($json_array);
$conn->close();
?>
```

The `$result->fetch_assoc();` returns an associative array.

As i said before i can see correct information using echo commands.

The problem is when i use this:

```
$json_array[] = array(''=>$key, ''=>$value);
```

The output is as follow:

```
[{"":"Mark"},{"":"ABC"},{"":"25"}]
```

Basically it's showing me only the second parameter "=>$value", while the first parameter "=>$key" is ignored.

Can you tell me please what should i change in order to see also the first parameter in my output?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to do that

`$json_array[] = array( $key => $value );`

instead of

`$json_array[] = array(''=>$key, ''=>$value);`

You are essentially adding an EMPTY string as key and the $key as value at first, and then you replace it with the $value as they share the EMPTY string key in the array.

Read more at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.array-func

Comment: Just tried your solution, but now i don't see anything, neither the second parameter. Could be wrong another part of the code i posted above?

Answer (score 0):

First param is ignored because it has the same key as the second (the key is ''), you should write:

```
$json_array[] = array($key, $value); // Indexed array
```

Output will be:

```
[["key1", "value1"],["key2", "value2"],["key3", "value3"]]
```

OR

```
$json_array[] = array($key => $value); // Associative array
```

Output will be:

```
[{"key1": "value1"},{"key2": "value2"},{"key3": "value3"}]
```

Comment: tried both solutions but now i don't see anything, neither the second parameter. Could be wrong another part of the code i posted above?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM People";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$json_array = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $json_array[] = $row;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo json_encode($json_array);
$conn->close();
```

In your code you are parsing only the first db result